# ¿Es posible optimizar ratings?

Tags: javascript

1. El código está funcional, el problema es que observo que hay partes que creo que se puede optimizar, claro, yo la he mejorado, hasta el punto que ustedes observan, ¿alguna idea para darle una mejor vista al código?
2. ¿Como hacer para que el porcentaje final de los ratings se le pueda agregar **toFixed(1)**?, ya que e intentado no funciona, lo ideal es hacerlo aquí para evitarlo de hacer después

```js
  const data = [{ rat: 60 }, { rat: 80 }, { rat: 80 }];

  // mayor rat primero
  data.sort((a, b) => b.rat - a.rat);

  // calculo de acuerdo al ranking
  let b = [];
  let e = 103;
  let i = 102;
  let c = 5.1;
  while (b.length < 51) {
    b.push({
      inp: (e -= 2),
      ini: (i -= 2),
      ran: (c -= 0.1).toFixed(1),
    });
  }

  let individual = [];
  let uni = [];
  data.forEach(function (a) {
    // filtra el ranking indiviadual  example 3.5
    const { ran } = b.filter((i) => i.inp === a.rat || i.ini === a.rat)[0];

    // no se unen los repetidos
    if (a) {
      uni.push({
        est: a.rat,
        nam: ran || 0,
        per: a.rat !== 0 ? 1 : 0,
      });
    }

    // unimos los repetidos
    if (!this[a.rat]) {
      this[a.rat] = {
        est: a.rat, // porcentaje individual
        nam: 0,
        per: 0,
      };
      individual.push(this[a.rat]);
    }

    // porcentaje individual
    this[a.rat].nam = ran || 0;

    // acumular personas por cantidad dependiendo rat example :  {rat:80 } {rat:80} 2 personas
    this[a.rat].per = a.rat !== 0 ? (this[a.rat].per += 1) : 0;
  }, Object.create(null));

  // 2. porcentaje final del ratings  
  individual.map((a) => ({
    ...a,// como hago para agregar el toFixed(1)?
    rat: (a["rat"] = (a.per * 100) / individual.reduce((n, m) => (n += m.per), 0)).toFixed(1),
  }));

  // creado ranking global examnple: 3.4
  const globalRanking = Number(
    (
      uni.reduce((n, m) => (n += Number(m.nam)), 0) /
      uni.reduce((n, m) => (n += m.per), 0)
    ).toFixed(1)
  );

  // creado porcentaje  global example: 68
  const globalPorcentaje = Number(
    (
      uni.reduce((n, m) => (n += m.est), 0) /
      uni.reduce((n, m) => (n += m.per), 0)
    ).toFixed(0)
  );

  console.log(individual);
  
  console.log(globalRanking);

  console.log(globalPorcentaje);
```

Comment: `Math.ceil(x*10)/10` y `Math.floor` para redondear hacia abajo

Comment: *Es posible optimizar. . . ?* R: Muy probablemente sí.